# Streaming trouble, ffmpeg unable to find a suitable output format

Tags: ffmpeg

FFMPEG for some odd reason won't allow me to output a stream, it's odd because I have two computers available and one, which had low CPU was having trouble decoding but the stream worked, so I switched my network cables and I have tried transcoding with the same command and it will not output a stream.

My command reads

```
ffmpeg -i udp://@xxx.x.x.xx.xxxx -f mpegts udp://@xxx.x.x.xx.xxxx
```

I also tried

```
ffmpeg -i udp://@xxx.x.x.xx.xxxx udp://@xxx.x.x.xx.xxxx
```

The error reads

```
[NULL @ 000001c95eeb2600] Unable to find a suitable output format for udp://@xxx.x.x.xx.xxxx'
udp://@xxx.x.x.xx.xxxx: Invalid argument"
```

full log

```
C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\Installations\FFMPEG\bin>ffmpeg -i udp://@xxx.x.x.xx:xxxx -f mpegts udp://@xxx.x.x.xx.xxxx
ffmpeg version 4.0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.3.1 (GCC) 20180722
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] no frame!
[mpegts @ 000001c3a9dea3c0] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] Reference 2 >= 2
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] error while decoding MB 62 39, bytestream 99129
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] reference picture missing during reorder
[h264 @ 000001c3a9dff900] Missing reference picture, default is 65373
Input #0, mpegts, from 'udp://@xxx.x.x.xx:xxxx':
  Duration: N/A, start: 87772.784411, bitrate: N/A
  Program 4030
    Metadata:
      service_name    : SONY TV HD
      service_provider: BSkyB
    Stream #0:0[0x208]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt709, top first), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x281](eng): Audio: ac3 ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 384 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x243](eng): Subtitle: dvb_teletext ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
[udp @ 000001c3aa7aaa00] getaddrinfo(xxx.x.x.xx.xxxx, 0): The name does not resolve for the supplied parameters
udp://@xxx.x.x.xx.xxxx: I/O error
```

Comment: Share full log for the first command.

Comment: I have added the full log

Comment: Right, so with your first command, you haven't supplied a valid IP address (`xxx.x.x.xx.xxxx`) and UDP is not a reliable protocol so your input has missing packets. This won't prevent you from streaming but output will likely have glitches and steam gaps.

Comment: I understand but since I'm new to using FFMPEG I'm wondering what you're approach to resolving this would be?

Comment: There's not much to resolve in this setup - provide a valid destination IP and hope your source feed doesn't drop too many packets.